# All Three Forms Get Empty in Single Click

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery

I have Three forms in a page with different submit button and all HTML are properly closed.
all forms have different value..now problem is when i press submit button of any form for store value in database..another form field is get empty..how can i prevent them for stopping them.i want when i press a submit button of any form only these form value submit in  database..other form field does not get empty..how can i solve this ..i have done coding for single form like this

```
        <form class="form" method="POST" name="pool">
  <label for="name1">Ist Player Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"  />
    <label for="name2">2nd Player Name</label></td><td><input type="text" name="sname"    id="sname"   />
 <label for="stime">Start Time</label>
 <input type="text" name="stime" id="stime" 
      <label for="stime">End Time</label>
       input type="text" name="etime" id="etime" />
<input type="submit" value="Confirm" name="pool" id="pool"  />
 </form>
```

same as 2nd and 3rd form .name are change of all form..and php coding of form like this

```
   <?php
   $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("snookar", $con);

   if(isset($_POST['pool']))
   {
    /* all procees to save record */
   }
     then 2 nd form
     if(isset($_POST['snooke']))
   {
    /* all procees to save record */
   } and so on...
```

now how can i done this only specified form value submit and another form does not empty...

Comment: stop using `mysql_*` functions. they are deprecated. use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Comment: In that Case you should Use Ajax Forms.

Comment: mysql is not issue.. my issue is i want all form does not get empty..only submitted specif form value and another form value remain in form till then they also are not submitted

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following,

```
<form class="form" method="POST" name="pool1">
     <!-- Form input fields -->
     <input type="submit" value="Confirm" name="poolbtn1" id="poolbtn1"  />
</form>

<form class="form" method="POST" name="pool2">
     <!-- Form input fields -->
     <input type="submit" value="Confirm" name="poolbtn2" id="poolbtn2"  />
</form>
```

Now use the `jquery` to submit the form,

```
$("#pool1").submit(function(e) {
   //Do your task here
   return false; //this will prevent your page from refreshing
}

$("#pool2").submit(function(e) {
   //Do your task here
   return false; //this will prevent your page from refreshing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The ajax script.**

> `$('input#form1button').click( function() {
>
>       $.ajax({
>
>           url: 'some-url',
>
>           type: 'post',
>
>           dataType: 'json',
>
>           data: $('form#myForm1').serialize(),
>
>           success: function(data) {
>
>                      $("#myForm1").resetForm();
>
>                     return false
>
>                    }
>
>       });
>
>   });`

Here in the above code form1button is the id of the button that is in the form i-e form with id myForm1
so repeat the same function for the rest of the two form with different form  and button ids

**Html**

> `<form method='POST' aciton='' id='myForm1'>
>
>   some inputs goes here
>
>   <input type=button id=form1button />
>
>   </form>`